# Chrome - Console warning about wrong MIME Type

Tags: javascript

I am writing a page which contains only a canvas in it's body and a simple JavaScript code.

In the JavaScript, I am creating an `Image`, but it's never appended to the page, instead, it runs through a [`timeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) loop loading a URL, which sometimes may return an actual image with MIME Type set to `image/jpeg`, or other times may return the text `NOIMAGE` with MIME Type `text/plain`.

When the url returns an image, the `Image` runs its [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onload) function, which will draw itself to the canvas in the page and decrease the loop's timeout interval.

When the url returns a text, the `Image` runs its [`onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onerror) function, which will simply increase the loop's timeout interval, not drawing it in the canvas.

This logic works very well, but it always throw this warning in the console when the browser try to set the `Image` as the text, which which increasingly consumes memory:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://localhost:6969/image.cgi".
```

How can I avoid this warning to be print over and over to the console?

EDIT: Added sample working code.

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
    </body>
    <script defer type="application/javascript">
            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var image = new Image();

            var timeout = 100;

            var timer = function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    image.src = "http://localhost:6969/image.cgi?timestamp=" + new Date().getTime();
                }, timeout);
            };

            image.onload = function() {
                console.log("Success");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.save();
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.restore();
        ctx.beginPath();

        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, parseInt(this.width), parseInt(this.height));

        if (timeout > 50) {
            timeout = timeout - 9;
        }

        timer();
            };

            image.onerror = function() {
            console.log("Error");
                if (timeout < 5000) {
                    timeout = timeout + 14;
                }

                timer();
            };

            timer();
        </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Show some code. It's really hard to tell what you are asking. How are you loading the image? And can't you check it's MIME type?

Comment: Instead of returning a string as text/plain, when an image is expected, just return e.g. the http response code `410 gone` or `404 not found`.

Comment: I will add a simplified code in a few minutes...

Comment: I added some code showing what I tried to explain.

Comment: To explain a little bit better: The URL `image.cgi` is a stream (and the parameter `timestamp` is used just to bypass the browser's cache). If I would be able to check the MIME Type prior to downloading it, my problem would be solved. But as soon as I would check the header for its MIME Type _and then_ download the image if MIME Type is `image/jpeg`, the content of the stream already changed, and now it could be a text.

Answer (score -2):

It might have something to do with your image being of CGI extension.  I've noticed a similar problem when trying to load JavaScript files that have an extension other than .js.  Take a look at this chart

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support

It has a chart in there of the supported image types for various browsers, CGI is not even labelled.

Comment: You are mixing server script technology and the output of the script. Basically the browser does not care if the image is static or coming from a CGI script.